# math built-in functions 'log'

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, python-3.5

I want to work with logarithms, but my math module doesn't work like it is supposed to.

Here's my code:

```
import math

n= int(2)
x = n**2
y = 2*n** log(3,2) +1

while float(x) < float(y):
    n += 1

print(n)
```

It prints the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\python\exp102.py", line 72, in <module>
    y = 2*n** log(3,2) +1
NameError: name 'log' is not defined
```

Can you help me put the math module work perfectly, if that's the problem?

Comment: it should be `math.log` as per your import statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a  function from a package, you have several options to do that. The two most use:

```
from math import log
```

This will make `log` available in the namespace and you can use it directly.

```
import math
```

This will make `math` available and you can access the function as `math.log()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import log module with below statement:

```
from math import log.
```